# Manage JSON server response on form submit in case of error downloading file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, error-handling, download

I've a simple jQuery code that asks a PHP server for a file download when the user clicks on a button:

```
// Build a temp form
var jRestr = {sFitxer: sFitxer, bDownload: true};
var $form = $('<form></form>').attr('action', getMBD_URL()).attr('method', 'post');
// Add the one key/value
$form.append($("<input></input>").attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'Consulta').attr('value', 'downLoadFile.php'));
$form.append($("<input></input>").attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'UserName').attr('value', sessionStorage.usuari));
$form.append($("<input></input>").attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'Token').attr('value', sessionStorage.token));
$form.append($("<input></input>").attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'sFormat').attr('value', 'META'));
$form.append($("<input></input>").attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'Modul').attr('value', sModul_glb));
$form.append($("<input></input>").attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'sjRestr').attr('value', JSON.stringify(jRestr)));
//send request
$form.appendTo('body').submit().remove();
```

This works like a charm, but if the server encounters some trouble (file not found, permission denied, etc...) it returns a JSON with error info instead of the file requested.

How can I catch it and display it in user-readable format?

I'm confused about which technique I could use, because if I use an AJAX call, I don't know how to download the file and if I use HTML submit call I lose the response control.

Comment: If there's a server error, the user is redirected to an ugly (response output) page?

Comment: @seak Can you show us how your error response look like?

Comment: Yeah, agree with @zayn-ali ... need the rest of your ajax code that shows how you are dealing with the rest of it. Probably would be best to initiate a check in your php code and issue a `return` that is caught by your an ajax success/catch.

Comment: this is the server response in case of an error: `{"sError":"File '2014-01-02 18.40.20.jpg' not found","lRedirectLogin":false}`

Answer (score 0):

Ajax isn't for downloading a file. You can instead just get the file name in response and then just redirect it

Your success function of ajax would look like this.

```
document.location = "download.php?filename=" + response.fileName;
```

and rest of work will be done by php response by these two headers.

download.php

```
<?php 

$filename = $_GET['filename'];

header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
```

Comment: I know how to handle an error ajax call, but how to manage the file download? As far as I know (not much) if I make an Ajax call, I loose the download when PHP returns `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= ". $aRestr['sFitxer']);` instead of `header('Content-type: application/json');` Isn't it?

Comment: mmm this is what is done in the first call to php (when all it's ok). Doing the `document.location = "path/to/the/process_file";`is a "magic trick"? which path may I put? I'm loosing on this last part

Comment: process_file is just your simple  php file which is just appending the filename to the header. let's say it's download.php and in it you've your code to append the filename which you grab from your response of the ajax call.

Comment: You mean that it works without adding any line to download.php?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120305/discussion-between-zayn-ali-and-seak).

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that **you can't download a file with ajax unless you redirect the document somewhere** (with JS **window.location** or a **submitted form**).

**The "right" way**

Create an endpoint in your server to check if the file exists (or has permitions etc) to be accessible easily with ajax and once this request is executed with a success response, then redirect (submit the created form) to get the file.

```
var url = "new_endpoint_to_check_if_file_exists";

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function() {
        // Here the code to append your form and submit to download file.
    },
    error: function(er){
       console.log(er);
    }
});
```

By the otherside, if you want control over the response **you're encouraged to use Ajax**, so modify the way your logic on the server works.

**The ugly way**

If you can't modify how the logic of your response works as mentioned previously, then theoretically you can still download the file but you'll need to make 2 requests to the same URL (2 times form submitted).

```
// The form Data
var data = {
    'Consulta': 'downLoadFile.php',
    'UserName': sessionStorage.usuari,
    'Token': sessionStorage.token,
    'sFormat': 'META',
    'Modul': sModul_glb,
    'sjRestr' JSON.stringify(jRestr)
};
// The request URL 
var url = getMBD_URL();

$.ajax({
    url: ,
    type: 'POST',
    data: data
    success: function() {
        // If the "file exists or there's no server error"
        // Generate the file download again
        // Build the form and submit again ...
        var jRestr = {sFitxer: sFitxer, bDownload: true};
        var $form = $('<form></form>').attr('action', getMBD_URL()).attr('method', 'post');
        // Add the one key/value
        $form.append($("<input></input>").attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'Consulta').attr('value', 'downLoadFile.php'));
        $form.append($("<input></input>").attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'UserName').attr('value', sessionStorage.usuari));
        $form.append($("<input></input>").attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'Token').attr('value', sessionStorage.token));
        $form.append($("<input></input>").attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'sFormat').attr('value', 'META'));
        $form.append($("<input></input>").attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'Modul').attr('value', sModul_glb));
        $form.append($("<input></input>").attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'sjRestr').attr('value', JSON.stringify(jRestr)));
        //send request
        $form.appendTo('body').submit().remove();
    },
    error: function(er){
       console.log(er);
    }
});
```

That should do the trick, however, i would choose the "right" way do it.

Comment: The ugly is so much ugly because of 2 transfers are requested. And the first option, good, but I'm very meticulous and I always expect that something can go wrong when calling to a server regarding you checked all you can imagine previously. If it's separated in 2 calls, the second call can crash and have the same problem as initial question :-(

Comment: Somebody told me that it's possible to get a file from an ajax Call using `window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, name);`. Is this or something like this an option? Or it isn't viable with large files?